# Converting <string> into float[]

Tags: java

Got this code (not working):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < splitSource.length; i++) {
        float[] nr = Float.parseFloat(splitSource[i]);
    }
```

I have an collection of strings...

```
  List<String> stringCollection = new ArrayList<>();
```

Previously, every string from the list is treated separately extracting from it the necessary and unnecessary characters and the final result is a string of pure numbers.
Now, I need to convert those numbers from String into Float, but i get the error of "float cannot be converted to float[]"...

Comment: Did you read the documentation of `Float.parseFloat()`? Is it supposed to return `float[]`? No? Then why are you assigning it to a `float[]`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
float[] nr= new float[splitSource.length];
for (int i = 0; i < splitSource.length; i++) {
        nr[i] = Float.parseFloat(splitSource[i]);
}
```

Float.parseFloat returns single float number, not array. Also, declaring float[] nr inside  for cycle makes no sense. Result will be lost when cycle ends.

Answer (score 2):

The method `Float.parseFloat(String)` delivers a float. Not an array of float. So just write

```
float[] nr = new float[splitSource.length];
for(...) {
  nr[i] = Float.parseFloat(splitSource[i]);
}
```